# Mocking Azure BlobServiceClient in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock

I am trying to write a unit test that will test `azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient` class and its methods. Below is my code

A fixture in the `conftest.py`

```py
@pytest.fixture
def mock_BlobServiceClient(mocker):

    azure_ContainerClient = mocker.patch("azure.storage.blob.ContainerClient", mocker.MagicMock())

    azure_BlobServiceClient= mocker.patch("azure_module.BlobServiceClient", mocker.MagicMock())
    azure_BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string.return_value
    azure_BlobServiceClient.get_container_client.return_value = azure_ContainerClient
    azure_ContainerClient.list_blob_names.return_value = "test"
    azure_ContainerClient.get_container_client.list_blobs.return_value = ["test"]

    yield azure_BlobServiceClient
```

Contents of the test file

```py
from azure_module import AzureBlob


def test_AzureBlob(mock_BlobServiceClient):
    azure_blob = AzureBlob()

    # This assertion passes
    mock_BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string.assert_called_once_with("testconnectionstring")

    # This assertion fails
    mock_BlobServiceClient.get_container_client.assert_called()
```

Contents of the `azure_module.py`

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import os


class AzureBlob:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """Initialize the azure blob"""
        self.azure_blob_obj = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(os.environ["AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"])
        self.azure_container = self.azure_blob_obj.get_container_client(os.environ["AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME"])
```

My test fails when I execute it with below error message

```
>       mock_BlobServiceClient.get_container_client.assert_called()
E       AssertionError: Expected 'get_container_client' to have been called.
```

I am not sure why it says that the `get_container_client` wasn't called when it was called during the `AzureBlob`'s initialization.

Any help is very much appreciated.

**Update 1**

I believe this is a bug in the `unittest`'s `MagicMock` itself. Per
Michael Delgado suggested that I dialed the code to a bare minimum to test and identify the issue, and I concluded that the `MagicMock` was causing the problem. Below are my findings:

**conftest.py**

```py
@pytest.fixture
def mock_Blob(mocker):
    yield mocker.patch("module.BlobServiceClient")
```

**test_azureblob.py**

```py
def test_AzureBlob(mock_Blob):

    azure_blob = AzureBlob()
    print(mock_Blob)
    print(mock_Blob.mock_calls)
    print(mock_Blob.from_connection_string.mock_calls)
    print(mock_Blob.from_connection_string.get_container_client.mock_calls)
    assert False  # <- Intentional fail
```

After running the test, I got the following results.

```bash
$ pytest -vv
.
.
.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<MagicMock name='BlobServiceClient' id='140704187870944'>
[call.from_connection_string('AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING'),
 call.from_connection_string().get_container_client('AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME')]
[call('AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING'),
 call().get_container_client('AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME')]
[]
.
.
.
```

The prints clearly show that the `get_container_client` was seen being called, but the mocked method did not register it at its level. That led me to conclude that the `MagicMock` has a bug which I will report to the developers for further investigation.

Comment: it seems like you're just asking about the proper usage of the `assert_called` feature. if that's the case, I think you would be more likely to get an answer if you dramatically reduced the amount of code and the complexity of your example. try to cut it down to the absolute minimum necessary to reproduce the question, and tailor your title and descriptions to attract experts in pytest, not azure blob storage experts. see the guide to creating a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am not asking about the `assert_called` feature.  I know what it does and I used it to assert that the `get_container_client` method was called during initialization. I could have used (and I have used) different features like `assert_called_once` or `assert_called_once_with` to test, but it fails as well. The reason I provided the entire code, so the people can see what I am working with and test/replicate on their on machines. Maybe I am using the patching the wrong way or something else....

Comment: right - you are asking why it's not working with your code. so you should be able to do the work of cutting down the complexity of your code until it includes the actual minimal amount required to reproduce the error. does this still work if they're all in the same file? what if `mock_BlobServiceClient` didn't include all that other stuff? what if you stripped out the first assertion, which is working? give [this post](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports) a read to see what I mean.